# How to make google play available in my apk

Tags: android

My android apk is using latest google play services.Some phone are not updated.So I wanted to make latest play apk available in my project and also a method for checking for latest google play services is available or not?
If not then I want some method so that user can install it So that i thought I can make apk available in my app or is there any other way to make user install latest play services?

Answer (score 0):

Include this into your `Manifest`:

```
<application>
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
...
```

And in code put this method which check play services:

```
protected boolean checkPlayServices() {
    final int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(activity());
    if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(resultCode)) {
            Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, activity(),
                    PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST);
            if (dialog != null) {
                dialog.show();
                dialog.setOnDismissListener(new OnDismissListener() {
                    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
                        if (ConnectionResult.SERVICE_INVALID == resultCode) activity().finish();
                    }
                });
                return false;
            }
        }
        new CSAlertDialog(this).show("Google Play Services Error",
                "This device is not supported for required Goole Play Services", "OK", new Call() {
                    public void onCall(Object value) {
                        activity().finish();
                    }
                });
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

And this is for version check:

```
int version = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.google.android.gms", 0 ).versionCode;
```

Comment: Thanks for the code but I'm having issues with the **CSAlertDialog**. The Android Studio is showing that the symbol `CSAlertDialog` cannot be resolved. In addition to that, **call** in the `new Call()` is having the same issue. **Cannot resolve symbol**.